# Why am I getting stuck in an infinite loop when trying to use this github project?

Tags: java, rest, curl, jira, x-ray

I am trying to use a Java Maven program that will allow me to import XRAY Cucumber tests off of a JIRA page using the RESTful API and am running into an issue with the demo where I am getting stuck in an infinite loop.  Here is the project link that will provide some more details and the project: https://github.com/kristapsmelderis/xray-test-automation-example
I know the problem is specifically in this method:

```
`    public static void importTestsFromJIRA(String username, String password, String jiraURL, String 
    jiraKeys, String pathToOutputFile) {
            String[] command = {"curl.exe", "-D-", "-X", "GET", "-H",
                    "Authorization: Basic " + encodeBase64String(username + ":" + password),
                    jiraURL + "/rest/raven/1.0/export/test?keys=" + jiraKeys, "-o", pathToOutputFile
            };
            ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder(command);
            Process p;
            try {
                System.out.println("\ninfo: Starting process that accepts curl GET command\n");
                p = process.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.print("\nerror: Tried to execute curl command and output to a file, something 
    went wrong\n");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            do {
                System.out.println("\ninfo: Checking if tests are imported and put in a new file\n");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                } while (!fileExists(pathToOutputFile));
        }`
```

I am following all of the instructions for the demo and have changed the system properties to what the original author has specified.  When I run the program I get stuck in an infinite loop of "Checking if the tests are inputted and put in a new file".  I suspect it is something to do with curl, although I believe I have set it up properly on Windows as the test command the author provided worked for me.  I am also connected to a company VPN on NetScalar Gateway while using this, could this be having an effect on the program?  Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems that the file pointed to by `pathToOutputFile` doesn't exist, whatever it is. Try looking into that, I unfortunately can't help you more than so.

Answer (score 1):

I may be off on this, but I believe the file name needs to be quoted in the cURL command line. All the examples in the [cURL man page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-o) have quoted file names after their -o argument.